# Building a virtual microphone using Electron?

Tags: python, audio, electron

I'm trying to build a virtual microphone that takes the physical microphone's input stream, modifies the audio using a neural network model written with Python, and replaces the sound stream with my program's output sound stream (in near realtime) so that other apps (e.g. Zoom, Skype, etc.) will receive my app's modified audio stream, for both Mac and Windows.

I've been reading for the last few hours and so far found several libraries that might (?) be able to work here: WebRTC, Soundflower, etc. Does anyone know if there's already a good library that can do or facilitate this? This might be wading into offtopic territory, but if this is doable entirely in Python, e.g. through eel or similar, does anyone know of any library that can do the same type of audio manipulation?

Thank you!

Comment: this is audio driver stack level of interaction and so is very OS specific

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create virtual microphone device using official [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista)